# How to allow multiple views use the same controller class?

Tags: ios, xcode, model-view-controller, delegates, uitableview

I've made a Model class called  DBcontrols  and I'm trying to use it in multiple views.  (I'm still trying to learn proper MVC technique on iOS.)  But the 2nd view, a TableVC, doesn't go to it.  I'm pretty sure my problem lies in the app Delegate, here called **dBAppDelegate.m**:

```
#import "dBAppDelegate.h"
//  Controller Class
#import "DBcontrols.h"
//  View Classes
#import "enterView.h"
#import "listTableVC.h"

@implementation dBAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    enterView *firstViewController = (enterView *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    listTableVC *secondViewController = (listTableVC *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    DBcontrols *aDataController = [[DBcontrols alloc] init];
    firstViewController.dataController = aDataController;
    secondViewController.dataController = aDataController;
    return YES;
}
```

**enterView.h** and **listTableVC.h** both have this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Contacts;
@class DBcontrols;

either:  @interface enterView: UIViewController
or:      @interface listTableVC: UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) DBcontrols *dataController;
   . . . 
@end
```

and that *dataController* is synthesized in both **enterView.m** and **listTableVC.m**

Here's the storyboard:

[image]

The Contacts TableVC, **listTableVC**, segues as a *Push* off of the *List* button on the **enterView** navigation bar.

All compiles successfully, but the DBcontrols methods are called in **enterView**, but not in **listTableVC**.  For example, in both **enterView** and **listTableVC** I use the method *countContacts*:

```
- (NSUInteger)countContacts {
    nC = 0;
    const char  *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM contacts"];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                nC++;
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%d contacts in dB.", nC );
    return [self.masterContactList count];
}
```

When this is called from **listTableVC**, it never responds.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on countContacts and/or in viewWillAppear.  Confirm the value of `dataController` in your two controllers.

Comment: Yes, that's where the problem occurs. In enterView, the dataController comes back with all the right values.  After clicking the LIST button and going to the listTableVC, the dataController comes back empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` the `secondViewController` won't exist yet.  The controller is created lazily; that is, when needed and it is needed only when the transition from firstViewController is initiated.

In a Storyboard context you normally 'pass' values using

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
  enterView   *source = segue.sourceViewController;
  listTableVc *target = segue.destinationViewController;

  target.dataController = source.dataController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listTableVC *secondViewController = (listTableVC *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Should be maybe:

```
listTableVC *secondViewController = (listTableVC *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
```

?